# how use information facebook to login in my application javaEE(jsp,servlet)

Tags: facebook, jsp, facebook-graph-api, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am developing an application using javaEE(servlet,jsp), and I want to give a choice for users to login to facebook, and start chatting on a public room using their facebook account. how could I implement this?
,and how I can get information like county,city,bith date,birth place...

Answer (score 0):

Try [Facebook4J](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html#how_to_use) or you can implement your own library that can utilize Facebook API.

You might consider this one [too](https://code.google.com/p/fbpwn/).